# how to convert DATESUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL X MONTH) to display the actual month

Tags: mysql

I have this code:

```
DATESUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL x MONTH)
```

where x is in a stored procedure. However instead of finding the date x month's ago, i need to just find out which month it was, and label it as its correct english.

For example todays month is December. If x was 2, it would return 2012/10/02. Instead of this I just want October

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL x MONTH), '%M')
```

If you were to use:

```
 select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%M') Month
```

It would return `October` as the result

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4502)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean `DATE_SUB` rather than `DATESUB`?  In any case, the `MONTHNAME` function will do what you want.  So the complete expression would be `MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL x MONTH))`.

Note that this won't always be the english name--the language it will give you depends on the mysql server's current locale.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname